# ckeditor, textarea only send value between tags

Tags: php, html, textarea, ckeditor

I'm using ckeditor in a textarea:

The code for the form:

```
    <form id="form" name="myform" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<textarea  name="content" >
   <?php echo $_POST['content']; ?>
   </textarea>
```

The form will be send to the current page, here is the code to insert the code into the database:

```
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if (empty ($_POST['naam']) or empty($_POST['content']) or empty($_POST['omschrijving'])  or empty($_POST['auteur']) or empty($_POST['keywords']))
    {
        echo '<h1>TEST</h1>';
        echo    '<script type="text/javascript">
                    alert("Er zijn velden die niet ingevuld zijn. Deze zijn met rood gemarkeerd");
                </script>';
    }
    else 
    {
        echo 'nog niet verwerkt';
        //alles is ingevuld
        $sql = "INSERT INTO sitecontent (ID, postnaam, post_inhoud, pagina, publiceren)
        VALUES  ( '" . $_POST['id'] .  "',  '" .mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[naam]) ."', '" .mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[content]) . "' , '" .mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[pagina]). "' , '" .  $_POST['publiceren'].  "' )";
        $query = $con->exec($sql);
            echo 'verwerkt';

    }
}
```

(I'm using PDO PHP :) ) There are some echo's for debugging my code.

Here is the code to change the textarea to a ckeditor:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace('content');
</script>
```

New my question ofcourse. If I post the content in the textarea, it will be insert into the database. And the inserted content will be displayed in the textarea.

I have an autosave function, the code is from stackoverflow. And it works fine. But if i change the value of textarea, it will only insert the code between the textarea tags.

So my problem is: my code will only insert the content from the textarea between the textarea tags.

I hope my question is clear. I can post the autosave code, but that works perfect for other input fields on the form. And it is the same code for inserting as above.

Sorry for my bad English, I hope you can understand me.

Thanks!

Comment: You mean it only saves the original textarea instead of the autosaved content?

Comment: Yes indeed, so only the code between the textarea tags.

Comment: Perhaps you could post the link from where you took the autosave function?

Comment: Ofcourse: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804528/periodically-autosave-form/5804818#5804818

Comment: Please **do not mix `mysql_*` function with PDO**. Learn how to use prepared statements.

Comment: Using PDO like this is like buying a car, just so you can take the wheels off and put them on your bicycle.

Comment: Hi I'm learing PDO and I'm converting my code to PDO. I need to change te mysql_real_escape_string into somthing else. I don't know what. You mean this: $query = $con->prepare($sql); before         $query = $con->exec($sql); ?

Comment: [Here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC). Read it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before you can submit the form, you need to tell CKEditor to save its contents back into the text area:

```
function CKupdate(){
    for ( instance in CKEDITOR.instances )
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
}
```

Then run `CKupdate()` before you save the form. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3256553/1338292

Comment: Thaks! I will try it later this day. Euh, do I need to fill in the name of the textarea?

Comment: Each instance of `CKEDITOR` knows what textarea field it's attached to.

Comment: You and so are amazing! It works perfectly! I just implement the code! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [autosave plugin for CKEditor](http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=24128).

Comment: Thanks for the answser! I don't want to use any plugins.

Answer (score 0):

First, I hope I can answer my question for this?
Above, they said I need to use prepared statements and don't use mysql_real_escape_strings.

I edited my code, this is code for inserting values in my database.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO sitecontent (ID, postnaam, post_inhoud, pagina, publiceren)
    VALUES  (:id, :naam, :content, :pagina, :publiceren )";
    $q = $con->prepare($query);

    $q->execute(array(':id'=>$_POST['id'],  ':naam'=>$_POST['naam'] , ':content'=>$_POST['content'] , ':pagina'=>$_POST['pagina'] , ':publiceren'=>$_POST['publiceren'] ));
    $q->errorInfo();
```

It works fine, and it is escaped in the database! But is this code realy save en good?

Thanks!