# Autosave a form without jquery or ajax

Tags: javascript, forms

I am looking to have an "autosave" feature on a system that is already established and I cant make very many/drastic changes to it. The form should autosave (aka submit itself) every time a change is made to one of the inputs. The way I have it now there is an onblur event bound to each input that submits the forms to processing.php which processes and redirects back to the form with the updated info.

This is fine and works well but loses the tab place and causes a "flash" from the reload. Is there a way I can autosave this form without the need for ajax or jquery? saving the variables to cookies and submitting the form when the person leaves the page? Or some other method?

Comment: What's wrong with only submitting the form on unload?

Comment: What is your objection against Ajax for this?

Comment: can onunload be used outside of the body tag? its a sort "application" where the user logs in and top and left sides are loaded only once and all navigation and content display afterwards is iframes being switched out for one another. The body tag is loaded only once.

Comment: objection of ajax is that it is a very complex system, and written quite some years ago, I do not feel like recoding everything to work for ajax

Comment: @11684 onunload seems to work, as simple as that, regardless of whether the body tag is outside of the frame containing the form or not. If you submit as an answer I will glady accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would propose `onunload`, it does what you want, it gives an opportunity to call a JS function if the user leaves the page.

Comment: Ended up using onbeforeunload instead as it has the cance to process before leaving the window. Same concept though.

Comment: Haha, I actually doubted if I should mention it in my answer, but decided not to! @cwal

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using AJAX for autosave, here is a version that does NOT use jQuery:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var form = document.getElementById('my-form-id');
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open(form.method, form.action);
    request.send(new FormData(form));
}, 10000);
```

If you want to send the form as `x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `multipart/form-data`, see my answer here: [Periodically autosave form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804528/periodically-autosave-form/51813482#51813482).